# How do I keep the Date format of my Data Frame in R when I convert it into an excel with openxlsx?

Tags: r

So I have a df that looks sth. like this:

```
Header1 Header2 01/09/2018 01/10/2018
ABCDEF  PP      529666     110735
GHIJKL  CC      720988     256444
```

When I use write.xlsx() on that df it sets the format of the headers for the columns 3 & 4 to "regular" in excel, but I want to save them as dates. 
Does anyone know how to do that? I´ve been searching the web since 3h and couldn´t find anything helpful.

Comment: See pg. 3 : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/vignettes/formatting.pdf

Comment: Have you tried saving your data frame as .csv (write.csv)? This keeps the Date format.

Comment: you can convert to all date-columns to character before writing to excel.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, Thank you very much. That solved my problem.